# Programmatic regression modelling with tidyeval

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang, tidyeval

I am trying to get my head around programming using tidyeval.

I want to write a function to run logistic regression models for selected outcome variables:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1234)

df <- tibble(id = 1:1000,
             group = sample(c("Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 3"), 1000, replace = TRUE),
             died = sample(c(0,1), 1000, replace = TRUE))

myfunc <- function(data, outcome){

enquo_var <- enquo(outcome)

fit <- tidy(glm(!!enquo_var ~ group, data=data, 
                family = binomial(link = "logit")), 
                exponentiate = TRUE, conf.int=TRUE)

fit
}


myfunc(df, died)
```

But get:

> Error in !enquo_outcome : invalid argument type

(note real scenario involves more complex function).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We need to create a formula for `glm` to pick it up.  One option is `paste`

```
myfunc <- function(data, outcome){
  enquo_var <- enquo(outcome)
   fit <- tidy(glm(paste(quo_name(enquo_var), "group", sep="~"), data=data, 
                family = binomial(link = "logit")), 
                exponentiate = TRUE, conf.int=TRUE)

fit
}

myfunc(df, died)
#         term  estimate std.error  statistic    p.value  conf.low conf.high
#1  (Intercept) 0.8715084 0.1095300 -1.2556359 0.20924801 0.7026185  1.079852
#2 groupGroup 2 0.9253515 0.1550473 -0.5003736 0.61681204 0.6826512  1.253959
#3 groupGroup 3 1.3692735 0.1557241  2.0181864 0.04357185 1.0095739  1.859403
```

---

If we also need to use the tidyverse functions

```
myfunc <- function(data, outcome){

  quo_var <- quo_name(enquo(outcome))

   fit <- tidy(glm(rlang::expr(!! rlang::sym(quo_var) ~ group), data=data, 
            family = binomial(link = "logit")), 
            exponentiate = TRUE, conf.int=TRUE)

 fit
}

myfunc(df, died)
#           term  estimate std.error  statistic    p.value  conf.low conf.high
#1  (Intercept) 0.8715084 0.1095300 -1.2556359 0.20924801 0.7026185  1.079852
#2 groupGroup 2 0.9253515 0.1550473 -0.5003736 0.61681204 0.6826512  1.253959
#3 groupGroup 3 1.3692735 0.1557241  2.0181864 0.04357185 1.0095739  1.859403
```

---

Or as @lionel mentioned in the comments `get_expr` can be used

```
myfunc <- function(data, outcome){

  quo_var <- enquo(outcome)

   fit <- tidy(glm(rlang::expr(!! rlang::get_expr(quo_var) ~ group), data=data, 
            family = binomial(link = "logit")), 
            exponentiate = TRUE, conf.int=TRUE)

 fit
}

myfunc(df, died)
#         term  estimate std.error  statistic    p.value  conf.low conf.high
#1  (Intercept) 0.8715084 0.1095300 -1.2556359 0.20924801 0.7026185  1.079852
#2 groupGroup 2 0.9253515 0.1550473 -0.5003736 0.61681204 0.6826512  1.253959
#3 groupGroup 3 1.3692735 0.1557241  2.0181864 0.04357185 1.0095739  1.859403
```

---

Or a more compact approach suggested by @lionel which avoids the `enquo/quo_name/sym` conversion instead directly takes the argument in `enexpr`

```html
 myfunc <- function(data, outcome){



   fit <- tidy(glm(rlang::expr(!! rlang::enexpr(outcome) ~ group), data=data, 
            family = binomial(link = "logit")), 
            exponentiate = TRUE, conf.int=TRUE)

 fit
}

myfunc(df, died)
#         term  estimate std.error  statistic    p.value  conf.low conf.high
#1  (Intercept) 0.8715084 0.1095300 -1.2556359 0.20924801 0.7026185  1.079852
#2 groupGroup 2 0.9253515 0.1550473 -0.5003736 0.61681204 0.6826512  1.253959
#3 groupGroup 3 1.3692735 0.1557241  2.0181864 0.04357185 1.0095739  1.859403
```

Comment: Ahh... that makes sense now. Thanks!

Comment: @PeterMacPherson  I added another option with tidyverse as well

Comment: thanks. I had previously tried with rlang::sym, but hadn't got the expr part. Many thanks again!

Comment: It is unidiomatic that you're creating a quosure and then serialising it with `quo_name()`. I think we need to be much clearer in the docs that `quo_name()` is not for programming, it's only for labelling, i.e. giving a default name in a data frame column and the like.

Comment: @lionel  The OP takes argument as an unquoted string

Comment: Also in your second example you create a quosure, turn it to a string, and then you convert it back to a symbol again. That's a lot of back and forth. I would just leave it as a quosure and use `get_expr()`. In the next rlang version there'll be `ensym()` to capture directly as a symbol (and check that the user has indeed supplied a symbol, with `enquo()` the user can supply anything).

Comment: what do you mean by "OP takes argument as an unquoted string"?

Comment: @lionet  I meant the argument is unquoted

Comment: @lionel I tried with `tidy(glm(rlang::get_expr(quo_var ~ group), data=data, 
            family = binomial(link = "logit")), 
            exponentiate = TRUE, conf.int=TRUE)` but it is not working

Comment: I guess once we have `ensym()` the proper way to do this will be `as_string(ensym(x))`. Anyway thanks for your contribution!

Comment: I meant `get_expr()` instead of `sym()`. `get_expr()` will take the expression of the quosure.

Comment: Or you can just use `enexpr()` instead of `enquo()` since you don't need quosures here. Then you can unquote it: `expr(!! enexpr(x) ~ group)`. I would also check that the output of `enexpr()` is indeed a symbol.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155389/discussion-between-lionel-and-akrun).

Comment: @lionel Is it a new function.  I get `Error: 'en_expr' is not an exported object from 'namespace:rlang'`

Answer (score 0):

Base NSE appears to work, too:

```
library(broom)
myfunc <- function(data, outcome){
  outcome_subst <- substitute(outcome)
  fit <- tidy(glm(paste(as.name(outcome_subst), "group", sep="~"), data=data, 
                  family = binomial(link = "logit")), 
              exponentiate = TRUE, conf.int=TRUE)

  fit
}


myfunc(df, died)



         term  estimate std.error statistic    p.value  conf.low conf.high
1  (Intercept) 0.8238636 0.1121528 -1.727556 0.08406792 0.6606245  1.025838
2 groupGroup 2 1.2587484 0.1571734  1.464102 0.14316606 0.9253116  1.713937
3 groupGroup 3 1.2490778 0.1550546  1.434369 0.15146698 0.9220209  1.693699
```